# How does "which" work in osx?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to install a linter for sublime tex in OSX. It cannot be found in sublime. According to the docs, this is likely because the PATH is wrong. It says I should try [this](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#finding-a-linter-executable):

```
hash -r
which linter
```

but replace linter with the "linter executable". I tried

```
which standard
which sublimeLinter-contrib-standard
which fooBarBaz
```

but neither of them returns anything. Do I need to execute this in a particluar directory or is something else wrong?

Comment: IMHO, `type` is preferable to `which`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`which` uses the value of `PATH` that it inherits. The fact that `which` returns nothing *confirms* that you need to add the appropriate directory to your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

`which` command looks through the directories defined in your shell’s PATH variable, as well as any aliases you have defined in your `~/.bash_profile` file, to find the location of the command given as an argument. This is useful when you want to find out exactly which version of a command is being used. Here’s an example:

```
$ which ls
 /bin/ls
```

This tells you that when you use the ls command, it is /bin/ls that is run. This command will also tell you if a specific command is a shell builtin.